# ASP Gridview design

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm pretty new to this.

I have an ASP gridview control so that in my program, when someone enters the email address and submits, the results are show (this works). What I was wondering is, is it possible to change the layout of the gridview so that not all results are shown on one line and so I can move some results to a new line below because if I add any more datafields, the one row will get even longer across the page.

If I could see some of your examples of different gridviews that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a repeater instead of a gridview you will have much more control over the rendered output...

You could then use divs instead of table columns and float them left with css. They would then wrap to the next line if there are too many "columns" to fit on one screen.